# What story is this from ? A feather chokes an opera singer to death on stage

Tags: identification-request

The audience at the opera watches a feather float slowly down and spiral into the mouth of the lead soprano, and she chokes to death.

I remember reading this sometime in the last decade, but don't remember when or where. I don't have any more information. I've searched Google but can't find anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for: an opera in which this happens or a story where people see this happening during a performance? I assume it's the latter, but I would appreciate it if this could be made more explicit. If it isn't from an opera, could you add more details about the story? E.g. length (short story or novel), the language in which you read it, when you read it (terminus ante quem).